# Is it possible to set up CloudWatch Alarm for 3 or 4 mins period?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, cloudwatch-alarms

I need to receive a notification each time a certain message does not appear in logs for 3-4 minutes. It is a clear sign that the system is not working properly. 
But it is only possible to choose 1 min or 5 mins. Is there any workaround?

Comment: How are you alerting when something does _not_ appear in the log file? Are using Amazon CloudWatch Logs with a custom metric? The standard alarm times in Amazon CloudWatch cannot be changed — you will need to select one of the available time periods.

Answer (score 1):

"does not appear in logs for 3-4 minutes. It is a clear sign that the system is not working properly."

-- I know what you mean, CloudWatch Alarm on a metric which is not continuously pushed might behave a bit differently.

You should consider using Alarm's M out of N option with 3 out 4 option.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-cloudwatch-alarms-now-alerts-you-when-any-m-out-of-n-metric-datapoints-in-an-interval-are-above-your-threshold/

Also, if the metric you are referring to was created using a metric filter on a CloudWatch Log Group, you should edit the metric to include a default value so that each time a log is pushed and the metric filter expression does not match it still pushes a default value (of say 0) thus making metric have more continuous datapoint.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you describe an cloudwatch alarm using AWS Cli it is possible to input the period in seconds.Only the web interface limits the period to set of values.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/describe-alarms.html